# Inaccessible virtual machine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My linux instances of virtual machines without apparent reason cease to be accessible and require their reset to login again. The machine from the management console looks normal. Does anyone could give me any idea that might be? Or how can see more details of errors VMs who are causing this problem ?, Thank you.

Comment: App Engine does not expose virtual machines, so your text suggests your tags are wrong -- erroneously using google-app-engine where you actually mean google-compute-engine.  Wrong tags make it unnecessarily difficult to offer you any support, so please edit your Q to fix either the tags or the text, whichever is in error.  Also, questions like this one are about system administration and not software development, so they're inappropriate for StackOverflow and better for ServerFault (don't worry, we monitor, and help on, both sites!).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to check the VM logs, from the Developers Console and the kernel itself.

From [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com), navigate to `Compute > Compute engine > VN instances > click on your VM > scroll down to View Output`

On the system side, depending on your Linux flavor you will need to check the system logs. Have a look at [this website](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/linux-var-log-files/) for more information.